# Put the value in textbox in center

Tags: php, html, css

Hi everyone i would like to ask you guys if how can i make the inputed value in the textbox go to center while the placeholder value will be remain on the left as always? help me please.

current code:

```
<style>
.number { text-align:left; }
</style>

<input type="text" class="number" placeholder=" 1.)" >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

style plcaeholder using css like this

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align:left;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:left;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:left; 
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align:left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdckj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

By setting `text-align:center` in CSS for your textfield like:

```
input{text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Well for this problem you need to take other alternate solution for  example take label and put you placeholder value there and position it left of your textbox and make textbox value center so your value will remain center and placeholder will remain left always.

Comment: use of placeholder is to act as hint which  hides in typing in textbox,but your soln will not works as placeholder concept